# AVCaptureConnection.previewLayer is nil in delegate AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate

Tags: swift, avfoundation, qr-code

The code below can run on an iPhone and when aimed at any QR code, should print the contents. The QR code below points to [example.com](http://www.example.com).

[image]

The problem is that the delegate should supply the `connection: AVCaptureConnection` and it does, but its `previewLayer` property is `nil`.

The following code can be pasted into a new, empty Xcode project. If you disable (comment out) line 57, and enable line 56, it works fine. But I want to place the delegate outside the `CaptureView` class. How do I set up the capturing such that `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` its `previewLayer` property is not `nil`?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

func printMetadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) {
    for object in metadataObjects {
        let visualCodeObject = previewLayer.transformedMetadataObject(for: object)
        guard let object = visualCodeObject, let barcode = object as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else {
            NSLog("Ignoring object that is not AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject")
            continue
        }
        
        guard let barcodeString = barcode.stringValue else {
            NSLog("Captured something that's not a string")
            continue
        }

        NSLog("Captured string %@", barcodeString)
    }
}

class CaptureView: UIView, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    private let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        printMetadataOutput(output, didOutput: metadataObjects, previewLayer: self.previewLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.frame
    }
    
    init(frame: CGRect, delegate: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate) {
        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find default capture device")
        }
        
        guard let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            return
        }
        
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        
        self.previewLayer.session = captureSession
        self.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()
        
        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
//        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(delegate, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
        } else {
            fatalError("Can't add metadata output to capture session")
        }
        
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class MetadataDelegate: NSObject, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let previewLayer = connection.videoPreviewLayer else {
            print("previewLayer was nil")
            return
        }
        printMetadataOutput(output, didOutput: metadataObjects, previewLayer: previewLayer)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    private let metadataDelegate = MetadataDelegate()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let captureView = CaptureView(frame: CGRect(), delegate: self.metadataDelegate)
        captureView.frame = self.view.frame
        captureView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        self.view.addSubview(captureView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [videoPreviewLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection/1390614-videopreviewlayer) documentation states:

> This property is the set if you initialized the connection using
> `init(inputPort:videoPreviewLayer:)` or
> `connectionWithInputPort:videoPreviewLayer:`.

So in order to get a value in `videoPreviewLayer` property you have to setup the `AVCaptureConnection` object manually.

Instead, I would suggest to hide `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` behind a custom protocol that you can declare:

```
protocol CaptureViewMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection, previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer)
}
```

then, implement the `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` protocol in your `CaptureView` and call your protocol's function passing the required `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. Your code will be like this:

```
class CaptureView: UIView, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    private let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    private let delegate: CaptureViewMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate
    
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        delegate.metadataOutput(output, didOutput: metadataObjects, from: connection, previewLayer: previewLayer)
//        printMetadataOutput(output, didOutput: metadataObjects, previewLayer: self.previewLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.frame
    }
    
    init(frame: CGRect, delegate: CaptureViewMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find default capture device")
        }
        
        guard let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            return
        }
        
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        
        self.previewLayer.session = captureSession
        self.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()
        
        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
//        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(delegate, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
        } else {
            fatalError("Can't add metadata output to capture session")
        }
        
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class MetadataDelegate: CaptureViewMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection, previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) {
        printMetadataOutput(output, didOutput: metadataObjects, previewLayer: previewLayer)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let metadataDelegate = MetadataDelegate()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let captureView = CaptureView(frame: CGRect(), delegate: self.metadataDelegate)
        captureView.frame = self.view.frame
        captureView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        self.view.addSubview(captureView)
    }
}
```

**Update**: After some research I did found this statement in the [init(inputPort:videoPreviewLayer:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection/1385882-init) function documentation:

> When using `addInput(_:):` or `addOutput(_:)`, **connections are
> automatically formed between all compatible inputs and outputs**. You do
> not need to manually create and add connections to the session unless
> you use the primitive `addInputWithNoConnections(_:)` and
> `addOutputWithNoConnections(_:)` methods.

Tha means tha when you added the device camera as input and the `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` as output, all the compatible `AVCaptureConnection` are created automatically.

I tried to create another `AVCaptureConnection` using the following code:

```
if let port = captureDeviceInput.ports.first(where: { $0.mediaType == .video }) {
    let con = AVCaptureConnection(inputPort: port, videoPreviewLayer: self.previewLayer)
    if captureSession.canAddConnection(con) {
        captureSession.addConnection(con)
    }
}
```

but the `canAddConnection(_:)` function always returns `false`.

After that I went and printed the `connections` array that the `AVCaptureSession` has and I saw following:

```
(lldb) po captureSession.connections
[<AVCaptureConnection: 0x280d67980 (AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x280d119a0 Back Camera) -> (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x280d6ba40) [type:vide][enabled:1][active:1]>, <AVCaptureConnection: 0x280d7bee0 (AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x280d119a0 Back Camera) -> (AVCaptureMetadataOutput: 0x280d700e0) [type:mobj][enabled:1][active:1]>]
```

So, an `AVCaptureConnection` has been created with the Back Camera as input and a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` instance (possibly the one that you created, the `previewLayer` property) and another one with the Back Camera as input and the `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` that you passed to `AVCaptureSession`.

The first one, obviously, did have some value to the `videoPreviewLayer` property:

```
(lldb) po captureSession.connections[0].videoPreviewLayer
▿ Optional<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer>
  - some : <AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer:0x280d6ba40; position = CGPoint (0 0); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 0 0); sublayers = (<CALayer: 0x280d6bc20>); masksToBounds = YES; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; inheritsTiming = NO; >
```

Apparently, the `AVCaptureConnection` instance that you are getting in `metadataOutput(_:didOutput:from:)` function will always be the second one. The one that is associating the Back Camera with the `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already implemented that workaround because no answers were coming for days. My original question remains: how do I set up the capturing such that `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` its `previewLayer` property is not nil?

Comment: @BartvanKuik I did some research but I didn't find anything that works. I updated my answer with just some things that I noticed for `AVCaptureConnection`.

Comment: Yup, when experimenting, I didn't use `canAddConnection()` and got crashes when trying `addConnection()`. It feels utterly strange to me: the metadata delegate is useless without "outside" information like the preview layer. But apparently, that's just the way it is. FWIW I've upvoted you and I'll leave this question open, perhaps someone else has an epiphany and solves it with a weird way of custom connections.

Comment: @BartvanKuik thanks for the upvote. It seams to me that a `AVCaptureConnection` always associate an input with an output. Since both `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` considered as outputs and you want information from the `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` you will never get there the `AVCaptureConnection` that has the other output. However, as you said, let's see if anyone else have a better idea.

Comment: @BartvanKuik sorry for the spam, but I also found that guide https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-qr-code and that guide https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/how-to-create-a-simple-qrcode-barcode-scanner-app-in-ios-swift-fd9970a70859 that do not use `transformedMetadataObject(for:)` function of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and work fine. So, maybe you don't need the `previewLayer` to get the QR information after all :).

Comment: I use the `transformedMetadataObject(for:)` function because in my production code, I added a smaller rectangular `UIView` over the preview layer. QR codes outside that rectangle are ignored. However, I now understand why the metadata delegate doesn't include this information -- it's really quite optional. I think this doesn't quite solve the question, however it does shine a light behind the reasons for this API.

Comment: @BartvanKuik yes, I did the same thing in an old project (the smaller rectangular `UIView`) In that case you need it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I caught the bug.

In fact, even if when you enable this line:

```swift
metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

in the correspondent `metadataOutput(_, didOutput:, from:,)` of `CaptureView`, `connection.videoPreviewLayer` is still nil. As the **Developer Documentation** says:

> This property is the set if you initialized the connection using init(inputPort:videoPreviewLayer:) or connectionWithInputPort:videoPreviewLayer:.

So, in both way, `connection.videoPreviewLayer` will be nil.

I've update your code a little bit to make it work the way you want.

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

func printMetadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) {
    for object in metadataObjects {
        let visualCodeObject = previewLayer.transformedMetadataObject(for: object)
        guard let object = visualCodeObject, let barcode = object as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else {
            NSLog("Ignoring object that is not AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject")
            continue
        }
        
        guard let barcodeString = barcode.stringValue else {
            NSLog("Captured something that's not a string")
            continue
        }

        NSLog("Captured string %@", barcodeString)
    }
}

class CaptureView: UIView, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if connection.videoPreviewLayer == nil {
            print("connection.videoPreviewLayer was nil")
        }
        printMetadataOutput(output, didOutput: metadataObjects, previewLayer: self.previewLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.frame
    }
    
    init(frame: CGRect, delegate: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate) {
        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find default capture device")
        }
        
        guard let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            return
        }
        
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        
        self.previewLayer.session = captureSession
        self.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()
        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
//        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(delegate, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
        } else {
            fatalError("Can't add metadata output to capture session")
        }
        
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class MetadataDelegate: NSObject, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let previewLayer = previewLayer else {
            print("previewLayer was nil")
            return
        }

        printMetadataOutput(output, didOutput: metadataObjects, previewLayer: previewLayer)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    private let metadataDelegate = MetadataDelegate()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let captureView = CaptureView(frame: CGRect(), delegate: self.metadataDelegate)
        metadataDelegate.previewLayer = captureView.previewLayer
        captureView.frame = self.view.frame
        captureView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        self.view.addSubview(captureView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, missed this one. Yes, I already figured out how to create/adjust a delegate. However what I meant with the question, was: how to (perhaps manually?) set up the connections such, that the `previewLayer` property of the delegate is filled in.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(